# Set Video Source From Project in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, video

im new in VideoView, i know how to set the link of video, but what if i want to add the video in my project and set the path of video. how can i do this? where do i need to add the video and set the path to play? it is in drawable? or something?... here is my code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

String path = "https://www.somethingvideo.com/yplay"; // The link i know

            VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.help, container, false);
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
            mVideoView.setMediaController( new MediaController(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mVideoView.start();
}
```

Thnak you so much!

Comment: A video would go in res/raw folder, assets folder or on the external storage rather than in res/drawable. Have a look at some of the questions about playing videos from raw or assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by placing your video file in your project `raw` folder. Create the folder if it does not exist. If you have a file named, for example, testmpeg.mp4, 
                you can set the video source using this code :

```
mVideoView.setMediaController( new MediaController(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" 
            + R.raw.testmpeg); //do not add any file extension, as it is fetched from the raw file

mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
mVideoView.start();
```

Comment: `Unfortunately, the application has stopped.` when running the application,
MY CODE:
`mVideoView.setMediaController( new` `MediaController(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));`
`mVideoView.requestFocus();`
`Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +` `"com.example.playvideo" + "/" + R.raw.help);`
`mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);`
`mVideoView.start();`

Comment: The logcat error is:
`12-22 17:05:13.270:E/AndroidRuntime(18316):at``com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)`
`12-22 17:05:13.270: E/AndroidRuntime(18316):  at` `dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: @Seynal That log error is not complete, You must find a line number on one of your classes. That is where the issue is.